# Azure Python Flask App which uses cors does not seem to install requirements.txt upon deploy?

Tags: python, azure, flask, web-applications

I have a small app written in Python that uses Flask and flask_cors.
I have added them to the requirements.txt file in the root of the project and when I do an az webapp up to deploy the site to azure, I expected azure to respect and install the requirements.txt file sent along. However the site fails to boot and somewhere deep in the logs I found:

> 2021-02-23T23:02:49.186395180Z from flask_cors import CORS,
> cross_origin 2021-02-23T23:02:49.186398680Z ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'flask_cors'

What is happening here? Should this not be installed automatically?

Here is a snippet of my requirements.txt file:

```
Flask>=1.0,<=1.1.2
flask_cors
pyopenssl
requests
...
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

TIA,
John

Comment: It is recommended to create a sample code, delete all sensitive information and business code, only for us to test, to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you must include the minimum versions and also it is "Flask-Cors".

```
Flask>=2.0
Flask-Cors>=3.0
```

Then you can go into Azure and check the deployment logs (I assume you are doing the quickstart found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=bash&pivots=python-framework-flask)

Go to deployment:
[image]

Then check out deployment logs:
[image]

Then you can see if you have installed what you needed: